# Getting the error "make: [Makefile:2: all] Error 127" when I use the make command

Tags: bash, git, makefile, cmake, centos

I am trying to install [this project](https://github.com/ggerganov/wave-gui) onto my computer and have been running into issue after issue.

The roadblock I've run into now is error 127. Most of the install works fine, until it gets to the step "make." I get the following output:

```
mkdir -p build && cd build && cmake .. && make
/bin/sh: cmake: commant not found
make: *** [Makefile:2: all] Error 127
```

I have tried installing on Git Bash for Windows 10 and using the terminal in CentOS. Both give me the same error. I have tried installing cmake on CentOS, but I'm unsure what to do with it now that it is installed. I also installed MinGW onto the Windows machine, but with no luck.

I'm relatively new to Linux/Unix (and very new to Git) so if the answer is obvious, I apologize.

I have found other questions similar to this, but the answer is always something along the lines of "it is trying to build something and it can't. need more context"

edit: Cmake is installed (as far as I can tell). I used this [walk through](https://gist.github.com/1duo/38af1abd68a2c7fe5087532ab968574e) to install it (updating the file names and stuff to correspond with the current version of cmake). The cmake directory was installed in the Downloads directory until I moved it (details below).

Someone had suggested that the cmake wasn't in a directory accessible to the $PATH variable. I moved it into a directory that I had added to the $PATH variable a while ago, but I am still getting the same error.

Edit 2: Alright, so I installed cmake through the CentOS software app thing. The make command works now, but theres a different problem. Running the make command outputs errors. The CMakerror.log file is filled with this over and over again:

```
Compilling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXComilerID.cpp" failed
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND
Build flags:
Id flags: -c

The output was:
No such file or directory
```

There are a bunhc of different entries like this, the only difference between them is that the Id flags bit sometimes has a "-c" but it also does "--c++" and "--ec++"

Edit 3: Here is the output from using the make command:

```
mkdir -p build && cd build && cmake .. && make
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
  No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.

  Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
  variable "CXX" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to the full path
  to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.


CMake Warning (dev) in CMakeLists.txt:
  No cmake_minimum_required command is present.  A line of code such as

    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)

  should be added at the top of the file.  The version specified may be lower
  if you wish to support older CMake versions for this project.  For more
  information run "cmake --help-policy CMP0000".
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/ellingtonj/wave-gui/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/ellingtonj/wave-gui/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
make: *** [Makefile:2: all] Error 1
```

I checked the CMakeLists.txt file and there is, in fact a cmake_minimum_required line (It specifically says "cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)").

Edit 4: A user below suggested I may not have gcc/g++ installed. So I used [this tutorial](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/centos-rhel-7-redhat-linux-install-gcc-compiler-development-tools/) to install gcc. Now I get error 2. Progress!! The ouput of the make command is below:

```
mkdir -p build && cd build && cmake .. && make
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 8.3.1
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Creating program 'wave-gui' with sources:
--    main.cpp
--    app.cpp
--    core.cpp
--    ui.cpp
--    data.cpp
CMake Warning (dev) in CMakeLists.txt:
  No cmake_minimum_required command is present.  A line of code such as

    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)

  should be added at the top of the file.  The version specified may be lower
  if you wish to support older CMake versions for this project.  For more
  information run "cmake --help-policy CMP0000".
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/ellingtonj/wave-gui
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/ellingtonj/wave-gui/build'
make[1]: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ellingtonj/wave-gui/build'
make: *** [Makefile:2: all] Error 2
```

Before anyone says it, yes, there is a makefile in the directory. Here is the output of ls for the directory I'm working in:

```
build  CMakeCache.txt  cmake_install.cmake  external  main      README.md
cmake  CMakeFiles      CMakeLists.txt       LICENSE   Makefile  src
```

Edit 5: I renamed "Makefile" on the off chance that it was looking for "makefile" and it kinda worked. I got a new error message which is good. Kinda. make ouput below:

```
-- Creating program 'wave-gui' with sources:
--    main.cpp
--    app.cpp
--    core.cpp
--    ui.cpp
--    data.cpp
CMake Warning (dev) in CMakeLists.txt:
  No cmake_minimum_required command is present.  A line of code such as

    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)

  should be added at the top of the file.  The version specified may be lower
  if you wish to support older CMake versions for this project.  For more
  information run "cmake --help-policy CMP0000".
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/ellingtonj/wave-gui
Scanning dependencies of target wave-gui
[ 16%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/wave-gui.dir/main.o
/home/ellingtonj/wave-gui/main/main.cpp:10:10: fatal error: cg_config.h: No such file or directory
 #include "cg_config.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/wave-gui.dir/build.make:63: CMakeFiles/wave-gui.dir/main.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:68: CMakeFiles/wave-gui.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [makefile:130: all] Error 2
```

Edit 6(?): my problem has changed so much that I figured a new thread should be made to more accurately reflect the problem I'm dealing with. [This thread is located here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64539139/fatal-error-cg-config-h-no-such-file-or-directory-error-when-trying-to-use-m)

Comment: "cmake: command not found" means you haven't installed cmake.

Comment: or `cmake` is installed in a directory that is not listed in your `$PATH`, so your shell cannot find it.  Review your variable (`echo $PATH`) to make sure `cmake` is reachable.

Comment: It would help us immensely to help you, if you were more clear about exactly what operating system you're using.  If you're using GNU/Linux then compiling cmake yourself is just a lot of work you don't have to do: cmake is already available for your system.  You just need to ask your package manager to install it.  If you have CentOS then something like `sudo yum install cmake` will do it.  If you have Debian or Ubuntu then something like `sudo apt install cmake` will do it.  This will install it and put it in a system directory which is probably already on your PATH.

Comment: But a hint: if you can't type a command at the shell prompt and have it found, then make can't find it either.  Make has no magical knowledge of where things live that your shell doesn't have.  As long as you get "command not found" when you type `cmake` at your shell prompt, then whatever instructions you may have followed, it's not yet fully available.

Comment: "Running the make command outputs errors." - Please, show that **output**. Content of `CMakeError.log` is not replacement for that output. (However, I suspect you simply have not `gcc`/`g++` installed.)