# "fatal error: cg_config.h: No such file or directory" error when trying to use make command

Tags: c++, cmake, centos, centos8

The previous stackoverflow thread for this is located [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64529531/getting-the-error-make-makefile2-all-error-127-when-i-use-the-make-comman). My problem has changed so much that I figured a new thread should be made. I am using CentOS8

I am working on installing [a tool called wave-gui](https://github.com/ggerganov/wave-gui) and having a real hard time (as you can see from the last thread). My current problem is that a file called cg_config.h is no where to be found when I use the make command (I also get errors 1 and 2). All of the troubleshooting steps that got me to this point are located in the previous [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64529531/getting-the-error-make-makefile2-all-error-127-when-i-use-the-make-comman).

I have copy-pasted the output of the make command below, and the contents of the "main" directory mentioned in the output below that.

```
-- Creating program 'wave-gui' with sources:
--    main.cpp
--    app.cpp
--    core.cpp
--    ui.cpp
--    data.cpp
CMake Warning (dev) in CMakeLists.txt:
  No cmake_minimum_required command is present.  A line of code such as

    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)

  should be added at the top of the file.  The version specified may be lower
  if you wish to support older CMake versions for this project.  For more
  information run "cmake --help-policy CMP0000".
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/ellingtonj/wave-gui
Scanning dependencies of target wave-gui
[ 16%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/wave-gui.dir/main.o
/home/ellingtonj/wave-gui/main/main.cpp:10:10: fatal error: cg_config.h: No such file or directory
 #include "cg_config.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/wave-gui.dir/build.make:63: CMakeFiles/wave-gui.dir/main.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:68: CMakeFiles/wave-gui.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [makefile:130: all] Error 2
```

```
app.cpp  CMakeLists.txt  core.h    data.h    ui.cpp
app.h    core.cpp        data.cpp  main.cpp  ui.h
```

Edit 1: Completely deleted the directory from the tool and recloned it and ran through the steps. Got a new error. This time it couldn't find SDL2. (yay progress!)

```
mkdir -p build && cd build && cmake .. && make
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 8.3.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 8.3.1
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "1.4.2") 
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
  Could NOT find SDL2 (missing: SDL2_LIBRARY SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:378 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  cmake/FindSDL2.cmake:173 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  CMakeLists.txt:16 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/ellingtonj/wave-gui/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/ellingtonj/wave-gui/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
make: *** [Makefile:2: all] Error 1
```

The SDL2 website says to simply use "sudo yum install SDL2." When I use this command I get the following output:

```
Last metadata expiration check: 1:25:41 ago on Mon 26 Oct 2020 09:54:58 AM EDT.
No match for argument: SDL2
Error: Unable to find a match: SDL2
```

Using the same command, but with SDL2-devel gets a similar output.

I used "yum search SDL2" and got this output:

```
Last metadata expiration check: 1:26:51 ago on Mon 26 Oct 2020 09:51:55 AM EDT.
========================================= Summary Matched: SDL2 =========================================
baresip-sdl.x86_64 : SDL2 video output driver for baresip
[ellingtonj@localhost ~]$ sudo yum install SDL2-devel
Last metadata expiration check: 1:24:08 ago on Mon 26 Oct 2020 09:54:58 AM EDT.
No match for argument: SDL2-devel
Error: Unable to find a match: SDL2-devel
[ellingtonj@localhost ~]$ yum search SDL2
Last metadata expiration check: 1:28:11 ago on Mon 26 Oct 2020 09:51:55 AM EDT.
========================================= Summary Matched: SDL2 =========================================
baresip-sdl.x86_64 : SDL2 video output driver for baresip
```

I then tried "sudo yum install baresip-sdl.x86_64" which gives me this output:

```
Last metadata expiration check: 1:25:25 ago on Mon 26 Oct 2020 09:54:58 AM EDT.
Error: 
 Problem: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides libSDL2-2.0.so.0()(64bit) needed by baresip-sdl-1.0.0-1.el8.x86_64
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)
```

Just for fun, I input "sudo yum install libSDL-2.0.so.0.so.0" and got another "no match for argument"

Edit 2: I followed the advice of yflelion and isntalled sdl2 glfw3 and fftw. I get this error now:

```
mkdir -p build && cd build && cmake .. && make
-- Checking for one of the modules 'glfw3'
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:640 (message):
  None of the required 'glfw3' found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:17 (pkg_search_module)


-- FFTW support enabled.
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
  Could NOT find OpenGL (missing: OPENGL_opengl_LIBRARY OPENGL_glx_LIBRARY
  OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:378 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindOpenGL.cmake:395 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  external/imgui/CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/ellingtonj/wave-gui/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/ellingtonj/wave-gui/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
make: *** [Makefile:2: all] Error 1
```

I'm looking into installing OpenGL now, but as noted in the previous thread I'm in way over my head right now. I also added (at the behest of several people) that I am using CentOS8.

Edit 3: I thought I had installed glfw3, but after installing OpenGL I got this error:

```
mkdir -p build && cd build && cmake .. && make
-- Checking for one of the modules 'glfw3'
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:640 (message):
  None of the required 'glfw3' found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:17 (pkg_search_module)


-- FFTW support enabled.
CMake Warning (dev) at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindOpenGL.cmake:270 (message):
  Policy CMP0072 is not set: FindOpenGL prefers GLVND by default when
  available.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0072" for policy details.  Use the
  cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  FindOpenGL found both a legacy GL library:

    OPENGL_gl_LIBRARY: /usr/lib64/libGL.so

  and GLVND libraries for OpenGL and GLX:

    OPENGL_opengl_LIBRARY: /usr/lib64/libOpenGL.so
    OPENGL_glx_LIBRARY: /usr/lib64/libGLX.so

  OpenGL_GL_PREFERENCE has not been set to "GLVND" or "LEGACY", so for
  compatibility with CMake 3.10 and below the legacy GL library will be used.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  external/imgui/CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Found OpenGL: /usr/lib64/libOpenGL.so   
-- Checking for one of the modules 'glfw3'
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:640 (message):
  None of the required 'glfw3' found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  external/imgui/CMakeLists.txt:12 (pkg_search_module)


-- Creating program 'wave-gui' with sources:
--    main.cpp
--    app.cpp
--    core.cpp
--    ui.cpp
--    data.cpp
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/ellingtonj/wave-gui/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/ellingtonj/wave-gui/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
make: *** [Makefile:2: all] Error 1
```

When I use the command "sudo yum install glfw" I gete the following output:

```
Last metadata expiration check: 0:07:49 ago on Mon 26 Oct 2020 12:24:38 PM EDT.
Package glfw-1:3.3-2.el8.x86_64 is already installed.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
```

Edit 4: installed glfw-devel and tried to run the make command once more. This time it got further than it ever has (again! Progress!!). Still getting errors though.

```
mkdir -p build && cd build && cmake .. && make
-- Checking for one of the modules 'glfw3'
-- FFTW support enabled.
CMake Warning (dev) at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindOpenGL.cmake:270 (message):
  Policy CMP0072 is not set: FindOpenGL prefers GLVND by default when
  available.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0072" for policy details.  Use the
  cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  FindOpenGL found both a legacy GL library:

    OPENGL_gl_LIBRARY: /usr/lib64/libGL.so

  and GLVND libraries for OpenGL and GLX:

    OPENGL_opengl_LIBRARY: /usr/lib64/libOpenGL.so
    OPENGL_glx_LIBRARY: /usr/lib64/libGLX.so

  OpenGL_GL_PREFERENCE has not been set to "GLVND" or "LEGACY", so for
  compatibility with CMake 3.10 and below the legacy GL library will be used.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  external/imgui/CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Creating program 'wave-gui' with sources:
--    main.cpp
--    app.cpp
--    core.cpp
--    ui.cpp
--    data.cpp
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/ellingtonj/wave-gui/build
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/ellingtonj/wave-gui/build'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ellingtonj/wave-gui/build'
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/ellingtonj/wave-gui/build'
Scanning dependencies of target cg_core
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/ellingtonj/wave-gui/build'
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/ellingtonj/wave-gui/build'
[  4%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/cg_core.dir/cg_config.cpp.o
[  8%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/cg_core.dir/cg_logger.cpp.o
[ 12%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/cg_core.dir/cg_glfw3.cpp.o
[ 16%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/cg_core.dir/cg_keyboard.cpp.o
[ 20%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/cg_core.dir/cg_mouse.cpp.o
[ 25%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/cg_core.dir/cg_timer.cpp.o
[ 29%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/cg_core.dir/cg_window.cpp.o
[ 33%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/cg_core.dir/cg_window2d.cpp.o
[ 37%] Linking CXX static library libcg_core.a
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/ellingtonj/wave-gui/build'
[ 37%] Built target cg_core
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/ellingtonj/wave-gui/build'
Scanning dependencies of target ImGui
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/ellingtonj/wave-gui/build'
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/ellingtonj/wave-gui/build'
[ 41%] Building CXX object external/imgui/CMakeFiles/ImGui.dir/imgui.cpp.o
[ 45%] Building CXX object external/imgui/CMakeFiles/ImGui.dir/imgui_demo.cpp.o
[ 50%] Building CXX object external/imgui/CMakeFiles/ImGui.dir/imgui_draw.cpp.o
[ 54%] Building CXX object external/imgui/CMakeFiles/ImGui.dir/imgui_user.cpp.o
[ 58%] Building CXX object external/imgui/CMakeFiles/ImGui.dir/imgui_widgets.cpp.o
[ 62%] Building CXX object external/imgui/CMakeFiles/ImGui.dir/examples/imgui_impl_glfw.cpp.o
[ 66%] Building CXX object external/imgui/CMakeFiles/ImGui.dir/examples/imgui_impl_opengl3.cpp.o
[ 70%] Building C object external/imgui/CMakeFiles/ImGui.dir/examples/libs/gl3w/GL/gl3w.c.o
[ 75%] Linking CXX shared library libImGui.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lXrandr
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lXi
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lXinerama
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lXxf86vm
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lXcursor
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [external/imgui/CMakeFiles/ImGui.dir/build.make:191: external/imgui/libImGui.so] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/ellingtonj/wave-gui/build'
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:159: external/imgui/CMakeFiles/ImGui.dir/all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ellingtonj/wave-gui/build'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:130: all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ellingtonj/wave-gui/build'
make: *** [Makefile:2: all] Error 2
```

This looks to be a problem with IMGui. Specifically the -lX----- stuff. I'm going to try and reinstall ImGui to see if that helps. Might restart the VM, too. Just to see if that fixes anything. Probably won't, but it doesn't hurt to try.
Maybe it's not accessible to the path variable or something?

Comment: You should run `cmake` from the top-level project's directory, not from the `main` subdirectory.

Comment: Which Linux distribution are you using? If you want to try installing by filename you need to give it the full path I think, i.e. `yum install /usr/lib64/libSDL2.so` or `yum install /usr/lib/libSDL2.so`.

Comment: You probably need the -devel versions of all of these packages, i.e. glfw-devel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On xubuntu 18.04 , in order to build this project I had to install:
libsdl2-dev libglfw3-dev libfftw3-dev.

To install them in Centos 7 (you mentioned centos in the previous thread):

```
https://centos.pkgs.org/7/epel-x86_64/SDL2-2.0.10-1.el7.x86_64.rpm.html  

https://centos.pkgs.org/7/epel-x86_64/SDL2-devel-2.0.10-1.el7.x86_64.rpm.html

https://centos.pkgs.org/7/epel-x86_64/glfw-3.2.1-2.el7.x86_64.rpm.html  

https://centos.pkgs.org/7/epel-x86_64/glfw-devel-3.2.1-2.el7.x86_64.rpm.html

https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-x86_64/fftw-devel-3.3.3-8.el7.x86_64.rpm.html
```

Enabling the EPEL repository as mentioned by @Rup would be a good idea.

Comment: For CentOS then you should [enable the EPEL repsitory](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) and then you can just install these by name, which will be simpler than downloading the individual files. For example you'll need SDL2-devel too, and possibly more.

Comment: Yes he will need the devel version of the libraries ( i updated my answer). And it will be better if he can enable the EPEL as you said.

Comment: This, along with downloading a few other devel things, worked! Thank you!